# onClicklistener covers scaleGestureDetector

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I set up a ZoomLayout like this: https://gist.github.com/anorth/9845602 , added a Framelayout and on the Framelayout I added some ImageViews.

These ImageViews have an onClickListener, so they change their color by activating their onClickListener.

The Problem:
When you want to zoom in by pinching with your fingers, it will only detect, if your fingers aren't on the ImageViews.
If your fingers are over them, the onClickListener of the ImageViews covers the scaleGestureDetector, as I found out.
The onClickListener doesn't trigger, if I'm moving my fingers to zoom.

Is there a solution to this problem?

I reduced the size of the ImageViews and it worked better, but then it was more difficult to click them, so it's not an option for me.

Edit: setclickable(false) works so there is nothing over the zoomlayout blocking the input. 
How can I make the difference between activating/deactivating the imageview onclicklistener or acativate zooming?

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I quickly looked into that `FrameLayout` & I can see that it has callbacks like `onScaleBegin`, `onScaleEnd` etc. You could listen for them in your activity or fragment & do something like which might help you,

```
public void onScaleBegin() {
    imageView.setClickable(false);
    imageView.setFocusable(false);
    imageView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
}

public void onScaleEnd() {
    imageView.setClickable(true);
    imageView.setFocusable(true);
    imageView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that it does not event start scaling, because there is the ImageView with onClicklistener over it. 
So there is no event to start scaling, because the triggered event is the onclick of the ImageView.
What I found out is that I can deactivate the ImageViews with the setclickable(false). But then I can't activate them, so it has to differentiate between clicking ImageView and start scaling.

Comment: I am not sure where you are placing your images on FrameLayout or how big they are, but if they are really like it covers the UI where user needs to interact, then it's design problem & you could do something like onTap of framelayout, hide the images so now user is in Framelayout interaction mode & then allow user to go back to normal mode with "X" button or something

Comment: There are a lot of small to medium sized images on Framelayout.
The user has to click on the images to color them. 
Because with bigger maps (more images = smaller), zooming is helpful, you should be able to zoom in and then click them (easier). 
The problem: You have images all over the screen and sometimes you zoom in by placing your fingers on the pictures -> not zooming in.
Only when placing between the images it zooms.

Comment: Not sure, but instead of implementing onClicklistener, try by implementing onTouch for ImageViews and detect if it was single tap, if not, then pass the touch event to framelayout.

Comment: Mhh, could be a solution. I'm going to have a look on that, maybe I can implement it that way. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: This is interesting, I will be back to home after few hours then try to make a demo nd see how to solve 
this exactly. Mean while best of luck and if you find solution, do post it here as well :)